# Mysqli bind_result error

Tags: mysqli, database-connection

I am new to SQL and PHP. My goal is simple: Check if there is already an email adress stored in database. I am using following code:

```
        $email = info@test.pl;      
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mysite"); // Create connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) { // Check connection
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $result = $stmt->num_rows;

        echo $result;
```

Every time i get an error. It says i am using wrong numbers of parameters in bind_result. How it can be?

Comment: Oh.. and i forgot. This is an error message: bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to all this, I would recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead of mysqli.

As for your error: you `select *` columns but bind only one. 
You can change the query to `select email`, or do away with binding the resultset:
if all you want is to check for the presence of the email, all you need is the rowcount.

Comment: You are a killer! thanks. It is PDO easier to handle or something? In every case i'll take a look on that.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, I find it easier - it's more standard, and, it's database agnostic, so you can change from Mysql to PostgreSQL or SQLite simply by changing the [DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) (although not all queries may be compatible) without having to change any code. It is very similar to mysqli though, but perhaps simpler to use.

Comment: If you want to check if the email is already in the database I would do it with this query:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts WHERE email = ?`.
It give you the number of matched rows.
Then you can check it with a simple `if($email){ echo 'Email is in database';}else{echo ' Email is not in database';}` because when there is any row $email will be > 0 which will be internal casted to true. If there a no row the result is 0 which is internal casted to false.